# Algebraic line bundles over $\Bbb{P}^1$ : Why is it enough to assume trivialization is given over the standard affine cover?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I am reading this MO post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16434/using-linear-algebra-to-classify-vector-bundles-over-p1) about the classification theorem of vector bundles over  $\Bbb{P}^1$. However, I am mainly interested in the case of just line bundles. Now if the general definition of a topological line bundle (over $\Bbb{P}^1$ say), the local trivialization condition states:

> > "***There is an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $\Bbb{P}^1$ over which we have trivializations...."***

However, in the MO post above it seems to be stated that given ***any*** line bundle over $\Bbb{P}^1$, it is enough to assume the trivializations happen over the standard open cover $U_0,U_1$.

> > **My question is:** Why is it enough to assume the cover is just given by the standard affine opens $U_0$ and $U_1$?

Comment: cohomology of $\mathcal{O}^*$ over affine open is trivial.

Comment: @Sanchez: Dear Sanchez, This is not true; e.g. already if you consider Spec $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3 - x)$, it has a huge Picard group (all the $\mathbb C$-points of the associated elliptic curve).  (You are probably thinking about the vanishing of coherent cohomology on affines, but $\mathcal O^{\times}$ is not even an $\mathcal O$-module, let alone coherent.)  Regards,

Comment: @MattE, Thanks! That's what I was thinking indeed.. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Sanchez: Dear Sanchez, No worries.  See Hartshorne, Ch. II, section 6 (I think) for a discussion of divisors/line-bundles in the affine context, and the relationship to the class group of $A$ (if say $A$ is locally factorial, e.g. regular).  Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Spec $A$, locally free sheaves of rank one correspond to projective $A$-modules of rank one.  But $U_i \cong $ Spec $k[x]$, and $k[x]$ is a PID.  Thus projective modules over it are in fact free, thus a projective module of rank one is just isomorphic to $k[x]$ itself, and so the associated invertible sheaf is just isomorphic to the structure sheaf.

In short, any line bundle on the affine line is automatically trivial.  (Replacing "one" by "$n$" in the above, we see that the same is true for vector bundles.  And in fact the same is true for vector bundles over affine space of any dimension; in the line bundle case this just uses that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ is a UFD, while for higher rank bundles it was conjectured by Serre and eventually proved (independently) by Quillen and Suslin.)

Comment: Dear MattE, thanks for your answer. However, my question is a little different. In the definition of a line bundle over $\Bbb{p}^1$, we require that there is an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ over which the trivializations happen. These open sets could be anything and don't necessarily have to be the standard affine open sets. However why is it enough to assume the cover that we started with was just $U_0$ and $U_1$? That seems to be what I get from the MO question. Regards,

Comment: @user: Dear user, I don't understand your comment.  What I wrote above is that the line-bundle necessarily becomes trivial when restricted to $U_0$ and $U_1$.  Thus it suffices to use this particular open cover.  Regards,

Comment: Dear @MattE, thanks for your comment. I think I am closer to understanding the full picture, though one thing is still bothering me. But one thing is still bothering me. Say I want to classify line bundles over $\Bbb{P}^1$. Given an arbitrary line bundle $(E,\Bbb{P}^1,\pi)$  over $\Bbb{P}^1$, I can restrict to $U_0$ and $U_1$ to get trivializations there. This means I have isomorphisms $\varphi_i : \pi^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i \times \Bbb{C}$ (for $i = 1,2$) satisfying the usual compatibility conditions. I now have transition functions $\varphi_1^{-1}\varphi_2$ and $\varphi_2^{-1}\varphi_1$.

Comment: @user: Dear user, The transition functions are not the primary object, the line bundle is.  And we have described the line bundle by giving its restriction to $U_0$ and $U_1$ (where it is trivial) and then giving the transition function on the overlap.  But, ... if you want to imagine that the line bundle is originally given via some transition functions on some open cover, then you can chase through and see the relationship with the new transition functions on $U_0 \cap U_1$ if you want to.  The main thing to remember is that the trivialization on $U_0$ and $U_1$ may not "be the same" as ...

Comment: ... the original trivialization (since a free rank one module will admit many different choices of basis), and you have to take that into account.  More technially, different choices of open covers with trivializations amount to different choices of Cech cocyle with values in $\mathcal O^{\times}.$  But any two different cocycles describing the same line bundle will differ by a coboundary (described on some common subcover for the covers arising in the two given trivializations).  Thus line bundles themselves are classified not by Cech cocyles but by cech cohomology classes, i.e. by ...

Comment: ... $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X^{\times})$. Regards,

Comment: Dear @MattE, reading your last two comments I realize now the issue of classifying line bundles over $\Bbb{P}^1$ is more subtle. Initially, I thought it is enough to look at the one transition function $t_{01} : U_0 \cap U_1 \times \Bbb{C} \to U_0 \cap U_1 \times \Bbb{C}$ but perhaps this is not the case. However what I do know is that such a transition function has to be an element of $(k[x]_x)^\times$, and thus of the form $x^n$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Am I right to say it is not enough to classify line bundles over $\Bbb{P}^1$ just knowing what $t_{01}$ has to be? Regards,

Comment: @user38268: Dear user, But $t_{01}$ is not a perfect invariant; you have to think about how it can change if you change the trivialization on either $U_0$ or $U_1$.  Related to this, note that the possibilities for $t_{01}$ are not just $x^n$, but $a x^n$ for any $a \in k^{\times}$.  (In terms of my previous comments, $t_{01}$ is a cocyle, but the true invariant is the associated cohomology class, i.e. $t_{01}$ modulo coboundaries.)  Regards,

Comment: Dear @MattE, thanks for taking the time to reply to my comments. I think right now I can be satisfied in knowing the issue of classification is not so easy. I now have more motivation to learn cohomology! If my naive approach won't work, do you know of a reference where I can read a proof of the fact that line bundles over $\Bbb{P}^1$ are all  isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(n)$? Thanks,

Comment: @user38268: Dear user, Just complete your argument! So far you have seen that the line bundle is determined by $t_{01}$, which is of the form $a x^n$ for some $n$ and some $a \in k^{\times}$.  The only issue is that $t_{01}$ is not *uniquely* determined; it can change if you chose different trivializations on $U_0$ or $U_1$.  But now just think about the possible ways that it can change ... .  Regards,

Comment: Dear @MattE, with renewed energy I will give this a shot. I will post a new question if I have some trouble with this. Regards,